# How to remove all lists with the same second[1] and third [2] item (python)

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like this:

```
[['15 802', 'unicom.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb']
 ['15 805', 'unicom.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb']
 ['15 999', 'bomba.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb']
 ['15 979', 'bomba.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb']
 ['15 989', 'bomba.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb']
 ['9 299', 'netmarket.png', 'apple-iphone-5-64-gb']]
```

I try to remove all lists with the same [1] and [2] item and to let just one of them. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Are the lines always complete duplicates like the example you showed? If not, what's the expected results when the first item is different?

Comment: [EDIT] The first elemnt can be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to add them to a dictionary with the items you want to filter for as the key:

```
>>> l = [['15 802', 'unicom.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb'],
        ['15 802', 'unicom.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb'],
        ['15 999', 'bomba.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb'],
        ['15 999', 'bomba.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb'],
        ['15 999', 'bomba.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb'],
        ['9 299', 'netmarket.png', 'apple-iphone-5-64-gb']]
>>> d = {}
>>> for item in l:
        d[(item[0], item[1])] = item

>>> list(d.values())
[['15 802', 'unicom.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb'], ['15 999', 'bomba.png', 'apple-iphone-6-16-gb'], ['9 299', 'netmarket.png', 'apple-iphone-5-64-gb']]
```